# In batch, is it possible to run a fc and an if %errorlevel% right after each other in a single for loop?

Tags: windows, for-loop, if-statement, batch-file

Basically, I am trying to write a batch file that will run an FC for all files in a directory (and its sub directory) and then run a separate batch script if an anomaly is found. Basically, the code is something like this.

```
(Upperpart_removed)

:main

for /f "delims=" %%F in (
'echo "."&forfiles /s /p "%folder1%" /m "%fileMask%" /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo @relpath" 
) do (
    fc "folder/path ... " & if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 "C:\Users\user\command.bat"

)

if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto main
```

Now the code looks a bit off because I had to redact folder paths and stuff (company security policy), but essentially every other line except for that fc ~~~ part is working. I am trying to figure out a way to run a batch file only if the errorlevel changes, and if its 0 just loop fc again. My current code ends up showing a "File not found" error but theerrorlevel remains 0 so the batch file isn't triggered. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Three ways: 1. use [`if ErrorLevel`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) syntax, meaning *if ErrorLevel is greater than or equal to* the given value – `fc "…" "…" & if ErroLevel 1 …`; 2. enable and apply [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) – `fc "…" "…" & if !ErrorLevel! neq 0 …`; 3. use [conditional execution operators](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) – `fc "…" "…" || …`…

Comment: in order to better service your request, you should at least tell us what exactly you've replaced with `Sth`, is it a command? a set? or a string? From what you have posted I can only assume that it is a file path, with absolutely no double-quotes, and that your code is actually reading the contents of that file, which I assume is a list of files names or paths, one per line. Therefore the first thing you should do is to check if the file exists first, and only execute `fc.exe` against those which do. When you redact information from your question, please do so more responsibly.

Comment: @compo sorry about the poor redacting, this is the first time I asked a question here so. The sth part is: 'echo "."&forfiles /s /p "%folder1%" /m "%fileMask%" /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo @relpath"    Folder 1 will get constantly updated with new info while folder 2 (which will get FCed alongside folder 1) will act as control so that we can detect new files in folder 1

Comment: You do not need a relative path to run `fc.exe` so there's absolutely no reason to use `forfiles.exe` inside the `for` loop. Why wouldn't you use `Dir "%folder1%\%filemask%" /B /S /A:D` to output the same directory list complete with full paths? It would be less overhead, and quicker, because the external utility `forfiles.exe` is running a separate `cmd.exe` instance for every item in the `%folder1%` tree, whereas the internal command `Dir` uses just the one. BTW, I agree with the first comment, the appropriate method, if indeed it is required, is to use `If ErrorLevel 1 …`.